# Perl: Using DBI placeholders for ORDER BY clause

Tags: perl, prepared-statement, dbi

Can I use placeholders in a prepared statement for the order by clause of my query?

I'm guessing not, as I tried it, and it didn't seem to work, but it didn't throw any errors either, which seemed strange.

Is there a better way to do this, other than just generating an SQL string with the validated inputs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't use placeholders for column name. From [DBI manual](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.609/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values):

> With most drivers, placeholders can't be used for any element of a statement that would prevent the database server from validating the statement and creating a query execution plan for it.

But still you can construct query in perl. In this case use [`quote_identifier`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.609/DBI.pm#quote_identifier) method to quote column name.

Comment: Don't sort in Perl. The database can do it better.

Comment: @friedo: Thanks for this hint. I've removed that part